# jquery how to remove ui-state-hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I use jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#dform").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      'Submit': {
        text : "Submit",
        class : "gbutton",
        click: function () {
          ...
        }
      },
      'Cancel': {
        text : 'Cancel',
        class : 'gbutton',
        click: function () {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  });

  $("a")
    .click(function(event) {
        $("#dform").dialog("open");
        $('button').removeClass("ui-button");
        $('button').removeClass("ui-widget");
        ....
        $('button').removeClass("ui-state-hover");
      }
  });
</script>
```

But mouse hover on button, style button changed to ui-state-hover. How to remove ui-state-hover? I expect that the ui-state-hover is added jquery code but I have no idea how to turn it off.

Comment: If you're just trying to change the appearance, edit the CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution

```
  $("button").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
  });
```

Comment: that works.. though you should probably use $(this) so it affects only your currently targeted element